# Importing MySQL database with special characters (é è ô à) (wordpress)

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, encoding, character

I'm trying to upload a MySQL Database into PHPmyAdmin, everytime I do so all the words with special characters are getting cut. Example "Carrières" becomes "Carri..."

Even worst, all of the post content doesnt appear from the special character to the end of the post. Is there à way to convert all the special characters of my DB or even better, a settings I can set before importation?

Thanks you to anyone who can help me with this.

Format of the DB : SQL
Encoding : UTF-8
Character set : latin1_swedish_ci
CMS : Wordpress

Comment: I would recommend trying to change the character set of the DB/tables to a UTF-8 character set (i.e. utf8_general_ci, utf8mb4_general_ci) and then see if the import works.

Comment: Better. Now my content (post) are showing up. Not being "cut" anymore, but theres a question mark "?" instead of the special characters (à é è)

Comment: This probably means that the document isn't being rendered as UTF-8.  You can either achieve this with a `<meta charset="utf-8">` meta tag, or have PHP send a `Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8` header.  The meta tag is the easiest of course.